# What article should I use in "If Mrs Hillier phones, say I'm away on trip."

Tags: articles

I would very thankful if you could please help with the following:

Correct the error/s in the following sentence:
"If the Mrs Hillier phones, say I'm away on trip."

What I've tried already:

1. If **(no article)** Mrs Hillier phones, say I'm away on **a** trip.
2. If **(no article)** Mrs Hillier phones, say I'm away on **the** trip.
3. If **(no article)** Mrs Hillier phones, say I'm away on trip.

What could be the right answer then and why?

Might you also please suggest some resources focused specifically on learning definite/indefinite articles usage?

Here's what I've found already:

https://www.englishpage.com/articles/index.htm

https://www.englishpage.com/articles/articles-flashcards.htm

Answer (score 2):

1. Let's first compare (a) "If Mrs. Hillier calls," (b) "If THE Mrs. Hillier calls," and (c) "If A Mrs. Hillier calls."

Normally we don't use articles with courtesy titles. So we would expect you to say form (a). If Mrs. Hiller calls, tell her so-and-so.

But suppose that in my apartment building Mrs. Ann Hillier lives in Apartment 1A and Mrs. Betty Hillier lives in Apartment 2B. If you bring a delivery and I can discern that you should deliver it to Mrs. Ann Hillier, I might say "You want **the** Mrs. Hillier in 1A." Where I'm trying to distinguish one from another, I might use form (b). But that doesn't seem to be a consideration in your example.

Now suppose that I only know one Mrs. Hillier, but you don't know her. I want to tell you what you are to tell Mrs. Hillier, but I know that her name will mean nothing to you. I might say form (c), "If a Mrs. Hillier calls," meaning "If anyone named Mrs. Hillier calls." I do this to keep you from asking me "Who is Mrs. Hillier?" By using form (c) I'm telling you that I don't expect you to place the name.

2. Next let's compare (d) "I'm away on trip," (e) "I'm away on the trip," and (f) "I'm away on a trip."

I cannot actually think of a situation in which form (d) would be correct. The word "trip" seems to require an article. But which article?

If Mrs. Hillier and I have been discussing a particular trip, and she will know the details without any explanation, it would make sense to say that I'm away on **the** trip, the trip we were discussing.

But if that's not true, and if (for example) I'm not actually on a trip at all but just asking someone to say falsely that I am on a trip, then form (f) would be most natural. Say that I'm on **a** trip, some trip or other.

So it seems like the best course here would be: If **a** Mrs. Hillier calls, say I'm away on **a** trip.